# How to kill a particular in memory session in IIS console?

Tags: iis-7, iis

I need to kill a user session if it's causing trouble on the web server due a web application bug as a quick workaround. Is it possible to kill only a particular in memory user session from the IIS console somehow without recycling and killing all other sessions as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Thought so. Unfortunately the app itself has nothing build in to kill the session.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But you would need 3rd party software to do it. But there is no way in the OS to accomplish this.

Check this software out. I just found this myself.

https://www.isdecisions.com/products/userlock/access-management-how-to-restrict-and-monitor-IIS-sessions.htm